# Facebook Workplace app Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, facebook

I use Facebook workplace app which doesn't have any linux app. Is there a way to install it (wine won't work for some reason) and get notified of new messages?
p.s.: regular facebook messenger won't work either

Comment: Hi Vasyl.  Welcome to AskUbuntu!  I presume that is a Windows application, yes? You say that Wine won't work for some reason.  Can you please update your question to include what happened when you tried running it with Wine?

Comment: @tudor The program WorkplaceChat.exe has encountered a serious problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience. This can be caused by a problem in the program or deficiency in Wine. You may want to check the Application Database(https://appdb.winehq.org/) for tips about running this application.

Answer (score 1):

I am in the same situation, instead of using wine, i created my own desktop app using Nativeifier ( https://github.com/jiahaog/nativefier ). Works like a charm and took all of 5 mins (if that)!! Full native workplace desktop app :-) Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

First, I got a bunch of errors relating to NTLM_Auth and wine-gecko, so I installed:

```
sudo apt install winbind
```

and followed the instructions [here](https://wiki.winehq.org/Gecko) by downloading wine-gecko-x86.msi and wine-gecko-x86_64.msi and putting them in `/usr/share/wine/gecko/`

The application starts and I got a menu, however, then I got these errors and it's blank in the middle:

wine: Unhandled exception 0x80000003 in thread c0 at address 0x1e78c0c (thread 00c0), starting debugger...
fixme:vkd3d_create_device: Unsupported feature level 0xc100.
fixme:vkd3d_create_device: Unsupported feature level 0xc000.
00d7:err:vulkan:wine_vkCreateInstance Failed to create instance, res=-9
00d7:err:vulkan:wine_vkCreateInstance Failed to create instance, res=-9
wine: Unhandled exception 0x80000003 in thread e9 at address 0x1e78c0c (thread 00e9), starting debugger...

The app is blank in the middle and pops up a dialog saying it's going to restart.

The problem above is that Wine doesn't yet have support for Microsoft's DirectX 11 with feature set 10.  I tried with DXVK also but that didn't work.

Your next bet is to do as the dialog suggests and [file a bug report](https://wiki.winehq.org/Bugs).

It's obviously also possible to run this in Windows inside VirtualBox if you need it urgently.

Answer (score 0):

friends, there is any PWA available for Facebook Workplace Like google drive ? https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive

[image]